# Using "this" keyword in image element using ionic framework and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

The following code is working fine, but when I use it in ionic framework and  angularjs it does not work. Does "this" keyword works in angularjs?

```
<img id="replace" src="empty.png">
<img onclick = "replaceImg(this)" src="apple.jpg">
<img onclick = "replaceImg(this)" src="orange.jpg">

function replaceImg(e){
  document.getElementById("replace").src = e.src;
}
```

when I use angularjs, "e" gets undefined.

```
<img id="replace" src="empty.png">
<img  ng-click = "replaceImg(this)" src="apple.jpg">
<img  ng-click = "replaceImg(this)" src="orange.jpg">

 $scope.replaceImg = function(e){
       document.getElementById("replace").src = e.src;
  }
```

Comment: "this" works fine in AngularJS. What else are you doing in your code?

Comment: It seems that when I try to get the passed parameter which is "this" from my controller, it gets undefined

Comment: For angularJS, use `ngclick` instead of `onclick` and pass `$event` instead of `this`

Comment: @morloch Thank you for your reply. When I use $event, I get the event name (in my case "MouseEvent"). I want to get the src of the img.

Comment: try `e.currentTarget.src` in your controller function. Although as @georgeawg points out, there is a more "angular" way to achieve the same outcome

Comment: @morloch Thank you. Both solutions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that in AngularJS:

```
<img id="replace" ng-src="{{replaceSrc}}" 
                  ng-init="replaceSrc='empty.png'">
<img ng-click="replaceSrc='apple.jpg'"  src="apple.jpg">
<img ng-click="replaceSrc='orange.jpg'" src="orange.jpg">
```